# SwingWorker doesn't update JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingworker

I have a class of my `SwingWorker` where I want to update data in `JTable` from **DB**:

```
public class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Monitor> {


    public DBMonitor dbmonitor;  
    Vector<Vector> rowData;
    Vector<String> columnNames;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    Monitor obj;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        dbmonitor = new DBMonitor();
        rowData = dbmonitor.getJobsData();
        columnNames = dbmonitor.getColumnNames();
        obj.setJTable(rowData, columnNames);

        while (!isCancelled()) {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SLEEP!");
            rowData = dbmonitor.getJobsData();
            columnNames = dbmonitor.getColumnNames();
            model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
            publish(new Monitor(model));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Monitor> monitors) {
        Monitor monitor = monitors.get(monitors.size() - 1);
        monitor.updateJTable(monitor.getModel());
    }

}
```

And `Monitor` class where  I render `Tabs`, `JTable` and execute `SwingWorker`:

```
public class Monitor extends JFrame{

    TableModel model;
    JTable jtable = null;
    JTabbedPane jtp = null;
    JPanel jp1 = null;
    JPanel jp2 = null;
    JLabel label1 = null;
    JLabel label2 = null;

    MySwingWorker worker;

    public void setJTable(Vector data, Vector columnNames) {

        jtable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtable);
        jp1.add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void updateJTable(TableModel model) {
        jtable = new JTable(model);
    }

    public Monitor() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        setTitle("Monitor System");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Panel with tabs for navigation
        jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        getContentPane().add(jtp);

        //tab1, info from dba_jobs
        jp1 = new JPanel();

        //tab2 info from QueueInfo
        jp2 = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("tab1");

        label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setText("tab2");

        jp1.add(label1);
        jp2.add(label2);

        jtp.add("Tab1", jp1);
        jtp.add("Tab2", jp2);

        DBMonitor dbmonitor = new DBMonitor();
        Vector<Vector> rowData = dbmonitor.getJobsData();
        Vector<String> columnNames = dbmonitor.getColumnNames();

        setJTable(rowData, columnNames);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);

        (worker = new MySwingWorker()).execute();
    }

    public Monitor(TableModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public TableModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

}
```

And in my `Main` method I execute:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Monitor(); 
    }
});
```

The problem is that, `showMessageDialog()` doesn't append, and `JTable` doesn't refresh.
I want update `JTable` from **DB** every 10 sec. [The Example I take from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JTable` does not update because when publishing you create a new JFrame (called Monitor) and set the new `TableModel` to it. You never show the new `JFrame`, nor do you update the already existing one. Hence, of course, you won't see any updates.

As for how to do this properly:

- You need to give your `SwingWorker` either a callback or a reference to the already existing `Monitor` (explicit via a variable, or implicit by moving it into an inner class). Only then will you update the correct `JFrame`
- Even then, you are creating a new `JTable` every time your model changes and not replacing your component. I.E. your frame will still show the old table and have the data for a new one (but will not show it). You need to either replace the table in the `updateTable` method, or (**much better solution**) update the model.

**EDIT**

An example of how this can look like (Assuming your column names don't change, if they do send them over just like the rows):

```
public class Monitor extends JFrame{

    TableModel model;
    Vector<String> columnNames;
    <other components>
    public Monitor() throws SQLException {
        columnNames = dbmonitor.getColumnNames();
        model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
        <Add all components, including table with the created table model>
        (worker = new MySwingWorker()).execute();
    }

    private class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Vector<Vector>> {
         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
             dbmonitor = new DBMonitor();
             rowData = dbmonitor.getJobsData();

             while (!isCancelled()) {
                 Thread.sleep(10000);
                 publish(dbmonitor.getJobsData());
             }
             return null;
          }

          @Override
          protected void process(List<Vector<Vector>> data) {
              Vector<Vector> lastPublish = data.get(data.size() - 1);
              tableModel.setDataVector(lastPublish, columnNames);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Beezy don't to create an JComponents inside Worker Thread(), please how mayn times is create GUI , there in place to add a new row to TableModel, intialized, created as local variable

Comment: +1, @Ordous please to remove everything about fireTableDataChanged(), is more than contraproductive, OPs creates DefaultTableMdoel, this motifier is implemented and corectly

Comment: Have you seen the example [I Take the Example From there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html)? There is the same situation and works fine, and just for experiment, I launched `(flipTask = new FlipTask()).execute();` in `public Flipper(){}` constructor. But the difference is, example updates `textfield`.

Comment: @Beezy note - the example publishes a data holder object, and the EDT updates already existing and visible components. You however publish a component created on a different Thread and never show it.

Comment: @mKorbel right, I've gotten so used to doing it with AbstractTableModel that I forgot there are other options.

Comment: @mKorbel, in `Main` method I added the code to create new `Monitor JFrame`, but MessageBox in code `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SLEEP!");` never append. It means that my code don't come to `doInBackground` method

Comment: @b `But the difference is, example updates textfield` - Yes, it uses the setText() method and doesn't create a new JTextField. My suggestion in your other posting was to `update` the JTable, not create a new JTable. That is done by using the `setModel()` method, which is the preferred approach because it will work for any TableModel. The approach given here will only work for the DefaultTableModel because the setDataVector() method is unique to that model.